# Airflow with systemd: `airflow.pid` vs `airflow-monitor.pid`

Tags: python, systemd, airflow

My systemd unit file is working (below).

However the `airflow-monitor.pid` file is transiently becoming read-only, which sometimes prevents airflow from starting. Our workaround is to delete airflow-monitor.pid if this happens. This is not the same file as airflow.pid.

It looks like `airflow.pid` is gunicorn and `airflow-monitor.pid` is a python process as airflow webserver.

**systemd unit file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
# by default we just set $AIRFLOW_HOME to its default dir: $HOME/airflow , so lets skip this for now
EnvironmentFile=/home/airflow/airflow/airflow.systemd.environment

#WorkingDirectory=/home/airflow/airflow-venv
#Environment=PATH="/home/airflow/airflow-venv/bin:$PATH"
PIDFile=/home/airflow/airflow/airflow.pid
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
# this was originally the file webserver.pid but did not run
#ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /home/airflow/airflow-venv/bin/activate ; /home/airflow/airflow-venv/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080 --pid /home/airflow/airflow/airflow.pid --daemon'
#ExecStart=/home/airflow/airflow-venv/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080 --pid /home/airflow/airflow/airflow.pid --daemon
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080 --pid /home/airflow/airflow/airflow.pid --daemon
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Here is the output of the pid files:**

```
airflow@airflow:~$ cat airflow/airflow.pid 
8397 
airflow@airflow:~$ cat     airflow/airflow-monitor.pid 
8377 
airflow@airflow:~$ ps faux | grep 8377 
airflow 26004 0.0 0.0 14224 976 pts/0 S+ 18:05 0:00 | \_ grep --color=auto 8377 airflow 8377 0.4 1.0 399676 83804 ? Ss Aug23 6:14 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080 --pid /home/airflow/airflow/airflow.pid --daemon 
airflow@airflow:~$ ps faux | grep 8397 
airflow 26028 0.0 0.0 14224 940 pts/0 R+ 18:05 0:00 | \_ grep --color=auto 8397 airflow 8397 0.0 0.6 186652 55496 ? S Aug23 0:32 gunicorn: master [airflow-webserver]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure why `airflow-monitor.pid` is becoming read-only, but you can avoid this pid file entirely by not running the webserver with `--daemon`. I don't think it's necessary with systemd.

Relevant block of code: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L754-L765

Comment: Nice find, this is in testing. I should have just grepped for `-monitor` from the get-go.